# How to define up and down arrow in custom android keyboard

Tags: android, keyboard

I have created android keyboard and I am creating arrows to move the cursor in the user input, I could do the left and right but I couldn't know how to write the code for the up and down .. here is the code

```
  switch (arrow){
    case KEY_LEFT:
      CharSequence leftText = getCurrentInputConnection().getTextBeforeCursor(1000, 0);
      int leftLen = leftText.length() ;
      getCurrentInputConnection().setSelection(leftLen-1, leftLen-1);
      break;
    case KEY_RIGHT:
      CharSequence rightText = getCurrentInputConnection().getTextBeforeCursor(1000, 0);
      int rightLen = rightText.length() ;
      getCurrentInputConnection().setSelection(rightLen+1, rightLen+1);
      break;
   case KEY_UP: case KEY_DOWN:
     break;
  }
```

can any one help me implementing the down and up ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to move cursors

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/InputMethodService.html#sendDownUpKeyEvents(int)

Try use sendDownUpKeyEvents method

```
sendDownUpKeyEvents(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT);
```

Will simply do the work.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I recommend doing something like this to check for key presses

```
    myEditText.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v,
                             int keyCode,
                             KeyEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                switch (keyCode) {
                    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT:
                        moveCursorLeft();
                        return true;
                    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT:
                        moveCursorRight();
                        return true;
                    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_UP:
                        moveCursorUp();
                        return true;
                    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN:
                        moveCursorDown();
                        return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

I'm going off the assumption that you're programming a text editor of some sort.

The implementation for up and down depends on what you want those buttons to do, and how you've implemented things so far. For example, you could have each line as its own `EditText` that is kept track of in an `ArrayList`. Then, each time you add a new line, you can add a new `EditText` to the `ArrayList`. And when a user presses up or down, you can just change the index of the `ArrayList` by 1 in the correct direction.

I imagine that would be a pretty inefficient way of doing it, but it would be easy to define what up and down do. It's difficult to say more about what you should do without seeing more of your code.

Comment: no I am creating just a soft custom keyboard without creating an EditText.. thats why I couldn't implement the down and up cursor .. do have any help idea of how this could be done ?